# Не видит зарегистрированного пользователя в сессии других контроллеров laravel

Tags: php, веб-программирование, laravel, laravel5

В контроллере LoginController `Auth::attempt()` работает корректно, пользователь аутентифицируется, но на других страницах фасад `Auth::check()` возвращает `null`, т.е. другие контроллеры не видят пользователя. Попробовал менять что-то в `Kernel.php`, пробовал использовать посредник *web* и *auth*,  но безуспешно.

Это код LoginController:

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function redirect()
    {
    return redirect()->route('home');
}

function loginUser(Request $request)
{
    $array = $request->except('remember');
    $remember = $request->has('remember');
$validator = Validator::make($array, [
    'name' => 'required|between:2,15|alpha_num',
    'password' => 'required|between:4,15|alpha_num',
]);

if ($validator->fails()) return redirect()->route('home')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();

if (Auth::attempt([
    'name' => $array['name'],
    'password' => $array['password']
], $remember)
) {


    //dd(Auth::user()); В этом контроллере работает корректно !

    return redirect()->intended('/admin');
    //redirect()->route('home')->with('message', 'Добро пожаловвать');
} else {

    return redirect()->route('home')
        ->withErrors(['loginErr' => 'Такого пользователя не существует']);
}

}
```

Это список маршрутов:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['breadcrumbs']], function () {
Route::get('/', 'IndexController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/map', 'MapController@show')->name('map');
Route::get('/map/categories/{cat_name?}', 'CategoriesController@show')
    ->name('categories');
Route::get('/map/nations/{cat_name?}', 'NationsController@show')
    ->name('nations');
Route::get('/map/seasons/{cat_name?}', 'SeasonsController@show')
    ->name('seasons');
Route::get('/map/{category}/{cat_name}/{article_name}', 'SeparateArticleController@show')
    ->where('category', 'nations|seasons|categories')->name('article');
Route::post('/incrementLike', 'SeparateArticleController@incrementLike');;


});


Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@loginUser');
Route::get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@redirect')->name('register');
Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@redirect')->name('login');


Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    //admin
    Route::get('/', 'Admin\IndexController@show');


});
```

Код breadcrumbs:

```
class BreadCrumbs
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        //если главная страница- не формируем крошки

        $crumbs = $this->getCrumbs($request);
        //dump($crumbs);
        if ($crumbs) $request->attributes->Add(['breadcrumbs' => $crumbs]);


        return $next($request);


    }

    public function getCrumbs($request)
    {
        $result = [];
        if ($request->path() == '/') return false;
        $arr = explode('/', $request->path());
        // dump($arr);
        $result[] = [route('map') => 'Карта'];
        //если находимся на категории
        if (count($arr) == 2 || count($arr) == 3 || count($arr) == 4) {
            $result[] = [asset('map/' . $arr[1]) => __('messages.' . $arr[1])];
            //если находимся в подкатегории
            if (count($arr) == 3 || count($arr) == 4) {
                $name = DB::table($arr[1])->where('alias', $arr[2])->first()->name;
                $result[] = [asset('map/' . $arr[1] . '/' . $arr[2]) => $name];
                //если находимся на рецепте
                if (count($arr) == 4) {
                    $tmpPath = route('article', ['category' => $arr[1], 'cat_name' => $arr[2], 'article_name' => $arr[3]]);
                    $articleName = DB::table('articles')->where('alias', $arr[3])->first()->name;
                    $result[] = [$tmpPath => $articleName];
                }
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Думаю,что проблема в сессиях , так так в ней ничего не остается.

P.S. Использую собственные контроллеры аутентификации(без `php make:auth`).

Comment: А у вас middleware breadcrumbs, как в Kernal описана покажите

Comment: @ Orange_shadow добавил

Comment: А ты смотрел оригинальную аутентификацию ?  там есть строчка  `$request->session()->regenerate();` может поможет, это после `Auth::attempt`

Comment: @Orange_shadow не помогло .не записывает банально session('user',Auth::user()), при том  что Auth::user() работает в LoginController.

Comment: А что у тебя стоит за драйвер сессии? смени ради интереса на array, а ты прова на запись в папку storage проверил ?

Comment: @Orange_shadow стоит файл.В storage сохраняются файлы.
Поменял на array - ничего не изменилось.А это нормально , что при обновлении страницы _token каждый раз новый ?

Comment: Нет, должен быть тот же, он по-моему в сессии и лежит

Comment: А ты смотрел этот [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29346743/laravel-5-session-doesnt-work) ? У тебя какая версия Laravel ? может ты не обернул в middleware web ?

Comment: 5-я версия.Ошибки аутентификации в сессию попадают  , а Auth::user так и не работает 
middleware web разве не идет уже в коробке ?

Answer (score 0):

Дело было в том , что родительском  контроллере всего сайта присутствовал dump(Session::all())
Закомментировал строчку и все работает.
Спасибо большое Orange_shadow.